# calculating time difference between 2 dates/times over more than 24hrs spans

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

What if the days are over more than 1 day. e.g Start Date 25/08/2020 02:17:36  - End Date 27/08/2020 23:48:58.

Is there a formula that covers for any number of days, above one?

Comment: How do you want the results expressed?

Comment: expressed in hrs,mins and secs

Comment: then it's just `=EndDate - StartDate` and format the results as `[h]:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1):

We can use your formula, but with careful formatting:

```
=(S36+T36)-(U36+V36)
```

[image]

In the above example, the difference is slightly less than 4 full days.
*(3 days, 21 hours, 20 minutes, 10 seconds)*

**EDIT#1:**

If you require the difference in **hours**, then use:

```
=24*((S36+T36)-(U36+V36))
```

with a standard numerical format.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend `[h]:mm` as shown in the DATEDIF documentation since OP asked about the time difference.

Comment: @EngineerToast  GOOD CATCH!! ..................I will update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "DATEDIF". [Here's the documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38). It can handle a variety of usecases.

Comment: How can this be expressed? My current formulae is  =(S36+T36)-(U36+V36).......S & T being the EndDate andTime

Comment: `DATEDIF` smallest element is a day. I would think the OP would be interested in finer granularity.